# Current drain into wall at home

Tags: wiring, electrical

I checked the wall near a plug with a Non Contact Voltage tester, and it showed electricity is present in a 3 meter diameter from the plug, on the wall. I think the wire inside has some contact with the wall. I was wondering if anybody knows for sure that if that would be the case, does it mean that I have a current drain? And I am paying for the electricity that I haven't used.

Thanks.

Comment: A probe on my finger showed about 60 V peak-to-peak voltage. Am I radiating power? No - not electricity. Am I worried? No.

Comment: I think since it can create a circuit with earth, it might drain a lot depending on the wall moisture.

Comment: 60V on finger is normal. You are a big antenna to E fields. This power into 10 M probe is meaningless.  Remember is E field is potential to produce power, not actual power.

Comment: I don't understand. I might have mention in the question. I did not mean 3 meter diameter to the air. I meant on the wall, and 3-meter-diameter around the plug on the wall.

Comment: If this wall is getting moist enough to conduct, you have much bigger problems.

Comment: It is moist enough to create a voltage 3 meters away from the plug.

Comment: those kinds of testers can beep at all sorts of unexpected times, no big deal...

Answer (score 1):

This is not an accurate method to measure power consumed.

It only measures E-Field potential at line frequencies, and not current .  The wires may act as an antenna for radiated E fields.  What you would need, is an H field sensor that measures the result of current flow , namely a Hall sensor or a single wire current probe.

I would not be concerned with this result.

Comment: Thank you Tony, but I don't have any of those. I can only turn off all the electrical equipment, and check the counter.
But you said that there is no concern. I have an argument here: If the wall has some moisture, it can create a circuit, and depend on the wall's moisture, it might have a low impedance, and hence consume a lot of electricity.

Comment: Moisture is an insulator and may act as a small capacitor.  If there is no arcing sound , why are you concerned?  If contaminated by ground water salts, there may be an issue then only measure at the breaker panel or monitoring the power meter with breakers off , then enabled one at time, can you isolate a fault and determine if the load is needed.

Comment: Why is moisture an insulator? It's not pure certainly and it helps the ions to carry electrons.
I am on the ground floor, and the moisture probably continue its way to the ground.

Comment: All insulators are dielectrics with some leakage. Water is one of them.

Comment: Ah, I understand now how you model it, but still I didn't understand why the water is insulator here. Pure water does not have considerable amount ions, but when we solve salt in to it, it's a very good conductor of electricity. Same here in the wall for instance we have CaCo3, which when is solved in the water makes it a conductor.

Comment: Tell me the resistance of a glass of "soft" water with your DMM using probes 1/3 spaced in cup. Then tell me if that is a conductor or a dielectric at 50Hz with e=80 (est 1nF~10nF ) , then do as I said with Power meter readings and breaker.

Comment: Normally ionic contamination across high voltage ( even 48V on phone line) will cause arcing called Partial Discharge (PD) when more rapid and worse , visible in air it is called corona) like a relaxation oscillator. I once had basement flooding the the phone wires were dialing pulses and calling 911 (LOL)  replacing the wires by tracing the RF with a transponder located the wires in the wall.  You need better tools to trace a water fault.. Like an AM radio to detect static arcing in a quiet channel.

Comment: Yes, thank you. I don't have enough tools, I only have a Multimeter and a NCV tester. I think you are right, it can form a capacitor, but it's a resistance too. I think I have to turn off all the devices, and wait and see if the counter is showing anything or not. Anyway, thank you for you patience. :)

Comment: AM Radio?  will pickup lightning 500 km away and tiny arc 10m away.

Comment: No, I don't have an AM radio, only FM on my phone. :)
I used to test remote controls with radio, but currently, I don't have it. I'm a student abroad, and not at home.

Comment: I don't understand the problem.  This is like 2 cups of coffee http://www.canadiansafetysupplies.com/product-p/300028.htm?gclid=Cj0KCQjwgb3OBRDNARIsAOyZbxBgw5Y4pMktPETkvJQSRBun67p2hR80P3m5q33CvlyAD7GLil5ACakaAvIHEALw_wcB  your education is all about learning how to LEARN, not the formulae.

Comment: Thank you. I wasn't thinking about buying it because I have no experience how to detect current with AM radio. I can work with remote controls, because I have a control over the keys, but I don' know how can I pick the current in the wall, maybe by changing the distance, but can I be sure that the current is the source of the signal I'm picking on the radio?

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a RCD (residual current device) rated as 30 mA on the electrical panel of the place? It is used to protect life on the cases of phase-earth accidents. If not, anyway you must have. If there is, then test it with the button on it. (You must test it on every at least 3 months) If it works, then residual current is small enough to not to worry about it. If it begins to randomly switching, you know the most suspected culprit, switch off its line fuse to prove it.